# tformfwd and tforminv - what's the difference?

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinate-transformation, inverse

Suppose I have an arbitrary transformation matrix A such as,

```
A =

    0.9966    0.0007   -6.5625
    0.0027    0.9938    1.0598
         0         0    1.0000
```

And a set of points such that their x and y coordinates are represented by `X` and `Y` respectively.

And suppose,

```
[Xf Yf] = tformfwd(maketform('projective',A),X,Y);
```

Now,

```
[Xff Yff] = tformfwd(maketform('projective',inv(A)),Xf,Yf);
[Xfi Yfi] = tforminv(maketform('projective',A),Xf,Yf);
```

`[Xff Yff]` and `[Xfi Yfi]` seem to be exactly the same (and they should).

Is `tforminv` just there for convenience or am I missing something here?

Comment: this seems to works for projective transformations, but what about the other transformation types (remember that **maketform** can accept a user-defined transformation, hence the inverse transformation does not always correspond to inv(A))?

Comment: Yep, I totally agree. But I'm only interested in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying it is my *best guess*...

It's possible that [`tforminv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/tforminv.html) may perform the transformation without actually forming the inverse matrix. For example, you can solve a system of linear equations `Ax = b` in two ways:

```
x = inv(A)*b;
x = A\b;
```

According to the documentation for [`inv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html), the second option (using the matrix division operator) can perform better "from both an execution time and numerical accuracy standpoint" since it "produces the solution using Gaussian elimination, without forming the inverse". `tforminv` may do something similar and thus show better overall behavior compared with passing the inverse matrix to [`tformfwd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/tformfwd.html).

If you were so inclined, you could probably try a number of different transformation matrices and test the two approaches (`tforminv` or `tformfwd` and `inv`) to see how accurate the results are and how fast they are each computed.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an answer along these lines

Comment: I've tested them for accuracy, and they're the same (I'm not concerned about speed at the moment, just accuracy).

Comment: @Jacob: If you were to use a transformation matrix that was badly-conditioned (i.e. close to, but not exactly, singular), the two methods may display different results.